# Select value on load and change

Tags: jquery, select

I have a select that appears on certain value (500) I need to be able to let it load on 500 and after it loads just change it to 50. I already managed to do this doing:

```
$select = $('select[name="content-table-redesign_length"]');
    $select.val('50');
```

however, even though the select value changes it doesn't reload the table as it would normally if the user were the one to change the value of the select. How can I make it emulate that change. Basically, how can I get it to do automatically what it does normally when a user changes the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$select.val('50').change();
```

This will trigger the change javascript.

Answer (score 0):

then applies the change to the select element :

```
$(select).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery trigger to trigger the onChange event

```
$select.trigger('change');
```